# Using cleveref for cross-referencing to exsheets questions

Tags: cross-referencing, expl3, cleveref, exsheets

I really like the functionalities offered by [`exsheets`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/exsheets), a package for typesetting exercise sheets and exam papers (and their solutions). One particularly nice feature is the possiblity of assigning labels to `question` environments. This is done by passing the `auto-label` package option, which, if no `label=<label>` option is passed to a `question` environment, uses the `question`'s unique `ID` to create a label, as follows:

```
\label{qu:<label>}
```

Unfortunately, that labelling functionality currently doesn't take advantage of the (clever) redefinition of `\label` by the [`cleveref` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref), my favourite package for typesetting cross-references. More specifically, `cleveref` redefines the `\label` macro as taking one optional argument in addition to its mandatory argument:

```
\label[<type>]{<label>}
```

The `<type>` optional argument is used by `cleveref` during a `\ref` call (`cleveref` also redefines `\ref`) to identify what kind of environment the referenced label is associated with, so that the correct cross-reference format be selected and typeset.

I'd like to patch `exsheets`'s `question` environment so that it create a label using `\label[qu]{<label>}`, not `\label{qu:<label>}`. That sounds relatively easy. Unfortunately, because I'm not familiar with `expl3` at all (yet), which `exsheets` is built upon, all my attempts have so far proven infructuous. Could anybody familiar with `expl3` give me a hand with this, please?

Below is some code describing what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\myQname{Q.} % macro for question headings (for more automation)

\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}
    \SetupExSheets[question]{name=\myQname}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
    \crefformat{qu}{#2\myQname~#1#3} % custom format for cross-ref. to a single question

\begin{document}

\begin{question}[name=Question, ID=foo]
    % Currently, 'ID=foo' (assuming 'auto-label') results in '\label{qu:foo}'.
    % However I would like it to result in 
    \label[qu]{foo} 
    % but that should be done by exheets "behind the scenes".
    %
    \lipsum[1]
\end{question}
%
Then, I could refer to that first question
using {\ttfamily\string\cref\{foo\}} (see below).

\begin{question}[name=Question]
    Do as in \cref{foo}, but use the following data instead:
    \lipsum[2]
\end{question}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the labeling is hard-coded into question environment. It would be easy to change this, though... So: another feature request? :)

Comment: @cgnieder I don't know if a lot of people use `cleveref` in conjunction with your `exsheets` package, so perhaps that feature doesn't warrant a new release; it's up to you. It sure would be useful to me, though :) Perhaps compatibility with `cleveref` could be offered as an `exsheets` package option; in that case, the user should ideally be able to specify the *type* associated with `question`s; it could be `qu` by default, but the user should be able to change that if s/he wants. I'm curious, though: is there no easy way of patching `question` without redefining it from scratch?

Comment: Currently the internal environment calls `\label` directly so you'd need to redefine it in order to change this... what it _should_ do is call a function instead that could be set as option or by redefinition... I'll add a suitable user interface.

Comment: @cgnieder I see. That would be great. I guess my question turns out to be a feature request, then :) Sorry for not posting it on [your bitbucket page](https://bitbucket.org/cgnieder/exsheets/issues/), but I originally thought I might be able to implement that feature with an easy fix. Thanks again for your help. I use `exsheets` more and more these days, and, as far as I'm concerned, it's ready for prime time. I think you should seriously consider v1.0 in the near future.

Comment: Thanks. If you have other feature questions now would be the time :) I could collect for a new update

Comment: @cgnieder I have another suggestion for a feature regarding a running sum of the points assigned to a question. I've added it as a feature request on your bitbucket page.

Comment: If you have more suggestions feel free to open more issues or drop me an email... the current list is long enough to justify another update soon... (I have some time this weekend)

Comment: @cgnieder Great news! I can't think of anything else at the moment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jubobs keeps me busy :)

Version 0.12 2013/12/02 (arrived in TeX Live today) implements the options

- `label-format` - the format of the automatically placed label when the `auto-label` option is used. `#1` is replaced with the questions ID. Default: `qu:#1`
- `label-cmd` - the command used for creating the label. This command should have one mandatory argument (and of course actually create a label...). Default: `\label`

So now you can do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[auto-label]{exsheets}[2013/12/02]
\usepackage{cleveref}

\SetupExSheets{
  label-format = {#1} ,
  label-cmd    = \label[qu]    
}
\crefname{qu}
  {\GetLCTranslation{exsheets-exercise-name}}
  {\GetLCTranslation{exsheets-exercise-name}s}
\Crefname{qu}
  {\GetTranslation{exsheets-exercise-name}}
  {\GetTranslation{exsheets-exercise-name}s}

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
  foo
\end{question}

\begin{question}[ID=bar]
  bar
\end{question}

Text \cref{1} text \cref{bar} text. \Cref{bar} \ldots

\Cref{1,bar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice :) I'll test that right away.

Comment: @Jubobs BTW: what always has been possible was placing `\label` manually in the question body but I guess you already knew that. This fix is only for the `auto-label` option (I had forgotten about that option until your question... :) )

Comment: Yes, I knew I could always put a `\label[qu]{...}` in the body of the `question` environment, but because I strive for automation (I'm pretty lazy), I was trying to hack  `exsheets` to get it to do `\label[qu]{<ID>}` automatically. I couldn't have done it alone, though. So thanks again! Are you still testing `exsheets`? I think it's likely to become the king of exercise-typesetting packages out there, if it isn't already. Do you have any plans for v1.0?

Comment: I've now tested your solution. Your v0.12 update of `exsheets` is awesome. Thanks again.

Comment: @Jubobs except that subtitles aren't working any more... next update is on its way

Comment: I hadn't noticed that.